# SQL Query, Selecting 5 most recent in each group

Tags: sql, mysql, select, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `codes` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `language_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `time_posted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

language_id refers to what language the record is in.
What I would like to do is retrieve a list of the five most recent (ORDER BY time_posted DESC LIMIT 5) records **in each language_id**. I could do this in a loop within PHP with a number of different SQL queries but I feel there is a simpler way.

I've got to get a book on SQL, haha.

Thanks.

Comment: What SQL engine? That's unfortunately crucial -- the SQL Standard, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, IBM DB2, etc, etc, have one superb way to do exactly what you want -- but if you're stuck with MySQL, that perfect solution working on every good relational DB and according to the standard itself is not available, so it's fudge-and-kludge time (par for the course for MySQL -- sigh). So what is it gonna be -- every decent SQL implementation on the planet, on one side, or MySQL, on the other...?

Comment: @Alex:  Quit beating around the bush -- let us know how you feel about MySQL!  Don't keep it bottled up.  ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I solve this "top N per group" type of query in MySQL:

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM codes c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN codes c2
  ON (c1.language_id = c2.language_id AND c1.time_posted < c2.time_posted)
GROUP BY c1.id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 5;
```

See also "[How do I select multiple items from each group in a mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304599/how-do-i-select-multiple-items-from-each-group-in-a-mysql-query/1326312#1326312)"

Comment: Sorry for being daft, but where did the C1 and C2 come from?

Comment: Note that if `time_posted` can have ties you might get some interesting results.  Let me know if this is a concern because it is solvable too.

Comment: @BillKarwin, this works for me (I have a similar use case), but I don't understand why I'd have to write "HAVING COUNT(\*) < 5" instead of "HAVING COUNT(\*) <= 5" to get a maximum of 5 entries for each group

Comment: @AlbertoSchiabel: If you want the top 5 per language, then by definition there for a row `c1` to pass the condition, there must be *fewer* than 5 other rows with a greater timestamp. Try it yourself: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a34d6/1/0

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great solution I just found.

Select the TOP n Rows For Each Group
Arnie Rowland, March 13, 2008

There are Multiple Rows for Each Category, and there is a desire to
SELECT ONLY the TOP two (2) Rows per Category by Price.
For example, from the following data:

```
RowID    Category    ID  Description     Price
1        Pot         A1  Small Saucepan  21.50
2        Pot         A2  1 Qt Saucepan   29.95
3        Pot         A3  1.5 Qt Saucepan 33.95
4        Pot         A4  Double Boiler   39.50
5        Pot         A5  Stewpot         49.50
6        Pot         A6  Pressure Cooker 79.95
7        Pan         B1  8" Pie          6.95
8        Pan         B2  8" Sq Cake      7.50
9        Pan         B3  Bundt Cake      12.50
10       Pan         B4  9x12 Brownie    7.95
11       Bowl        C1  Lg Mixing       27.50
12       Bowl        C2  Sm Mixing       17.50
13       Tools       T1  14" Spatula     9.95
```

The desired output is:

```
RowID    Category    ID  Description     Price
11       Bowl        C1  Lg Mixing       27.50
12       Bowl        C2  Sm Mixing       17.50
9        Pan         B3  Bundt Cake      12.50
10       Pan         B4  9x12 Brownie    7.95
6        Pot         A6  Pressure Cooker 79.95
5        Pot         A5  Stewpot         49.50
13       Tools       T1  14" Spatula     9.95
```

There are several methods to accomplish the desired output. 
This demonstration provides a Solution for SQL Server 2005 / SQL Server 2008 , 
and then a Solution for SQL Server 2000.

Create Sample Data for Both Solutions

```
-- Suppress data loading messages
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Create Sample Data using a Table Variable
DECLARE @MyTable table
   (  RowID         int   IDENTITY, 
      Category      varchar(5),
      [ID]          varchar(5),
      [Description] varchar(25),
      Price         decimal(10,2)
   )

-- Load Sample Data

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pot', 'A1', 'Small Saucepan', 21.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pot', 'A2', '1 Qt Saucepan', 29.95 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pot', 'A3', '1.5 Qt Saucepan', 33.95 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pot', 'A4', 'Double Boiler', 39.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pot', 'A5', 'Stewpot', 49.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pot', 'A6', 'Pressure Cooker', 79.95 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pan', 'B1', '8"" Pie', 6.95 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pan', 'B2', '8"" Sq Cake', 7.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pan', 'B3', 'Bundt Cake', 12.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Pan', 'B4', '9x12 Brownie', 7.95 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Bowl', 'C1', 'Lg Mixing', 27.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Bowl', 'C2', 'Sm Mixing', 17.50 )
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ( 'Tools', 'T1', '14"" Spatula', 9.95 )
Return to Top
```

SQL Server 2005 / SQL Server 2008 Solution

```
--Query to Retrieve Desired Data
SELECT
   RowID,
   Category,
   [ID],
   [Description],
   Price
FROM (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Price DESC ) AS 'RowNumber',
         RowID,
         Category,
         [ID],
         [Description],
         Price
      FROM @MyTable
      ) dt
WHERE RowNumber <= 2

-- Results
RowID Category  ID Description     Price
11    Bowl      C1 Lg Mixing       27.50
12    Bowl      C2 Sm Mixing       17.50
9     Pan       B3 Bundt Cake      12.50
10    Pan       B4 9x12 Brownie    7.95
6     Pot       A6 Pressure Cooker 79.95
5     Pot       A5 Stewpot         49.50
13    Tools     T1 14" Spatula     9.95
Return to Top
```

SQL Server 2005 / SQL Server 2008 Solution using a CTE
(Added by: Jacob Sebastian)

```
-- Define a CTE with the name "dt" 
;WITH dt AS (
     SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Price DESC ) AS 'RowNumber',
         RowID,
         Category,
         [ID],
         [Description],
         Price
      FROM @MyTable
)
-- and select the data from the CTE
SELECT
   RowID,
   Category,
   [ID],
   [Description],
   Price
FROM dt
WHERE RowNumber <= 2

-- Results
RowID Category  ID Description     Price
11    Bowl      C1 Lg Mixing       27.50
12    Bowl      C2 Sm Mixing       17.50
9     Pan       B3 Bundt Cake      12.50
10    Pan       B4 9x12 Brownie    7.95
6     Pot       A6 Pressure Cooker 79.95
5     Pot       A5 Stewpot         49.50
13    Tools     T1 14" Spatula     9.95
Return to Top
```

SQL 2000 Solution

```
--Query to Retrieve Desired Data
SELECT DISTINCT
   RowID,
   Category,
   [ID],
   [Description],
   Price
FROM @MyTable t1
WHERE RowID IN (SELECT TOP 2
                   RowID
                FROM @MyTable t2
                WHERE t2.Category = t1.Category
                ORDER BY Price DESC
               )
ORDER BY 
   Category,
   Price DESC

-- Results
RowID Category  ID Description     Price
11    Bowl      C1 Lg Mixing       27.50
12    Bowl      C2 Sm Mixing       17.50
9     Pan       B3 Bundt Cake      12.50
10    Pan       B4 9x12 Brownie    7.95
6     Pot       A6 Pressure Cooker 79.95
5     Pot       A5 Stewpot         49.50
13    Tools     T1 14" Spatula     9.95
```

From: [Select the TOP n Rows For Each Group](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SelectTopNByGroup)

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.