# sql for finding most recent record in a group

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i have a table like such

```
table_id | series_id | revision_id | year
------------------------------------------
1        | 1         | 1           | 2010
2        | 2         | 1           | 2009
3        | 2         | 2           | 2008
4        | 2         | 2           | 2009
5        | 2         | 3           | 2010
6        | 2         | 3           | 2008
7        | 3         | 2           | 2007
8        | 3         | 3           | 2010
9        | 3         | 3           | 2010
```

I need to find the table_id for the max(year) when grouped by revision_id when series = X
in postgresql.

eg : when x =2 i expect this result

```
table_id | series_id | revision_id | year
------------------------------------------
2        | 2         | 1           | 2009
4        | 2         | 2           | 2009
5        | 2         | 3           | 2010
```

this doesn't work

```
SELECT * from table 
WHERE series_id = 2 
AND table_id IN (
    SELECT table_id 
    FROM table 
    WHERE series_id = 2 
    GROUP by revision 
    ORDER BY year DESC
)
```

I cannot figure out a way to do this in postgresql since I need to return a field i am not grouping by

here are some similar problems in other SQL flavors.

MySQL 
[SQL Query, Selecting 5 most recent in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353099/sql-query-selecting-5-most-recent-in-each-group)

SQL SERVER
[SQL Server - How to select the most recent record per user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320677/sql-server-how-to-select-the-most-recent-record-per-user)

Comment: And the solutions to those problems don't work...?

Comment: mysql allows you to select a field that is not in the group by, which is not allowed in postgres.  SQL server's TOP1 is not supported either.

Comment: Unless you are somehow picking only the top record, I do not reccommend ordering by anthing in a subquery, as the sort is discarded immediately afterwards (by SQL standard).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT table_id, series_id, revision_id, year
FROM tableName t INNER JOIN
    (SELECT revision_id, max(year) AS year
    FROM tableName 
    WHERE series_id = 2 
    GROUP BY revision_id) s
USING (revision_id, year)
WHERE series_id = 2;
```

Result:

```
 table_id | series_id | revision_id | year
----------+-----------+-------------+------
        2 |         2 |           1 | 2009
        4 |         2 |           2 | 2009
        5 |         2 |           3 | 2010
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm...
Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table as a
WHERE series_id = ?
AND year = (SELECT MAX(year)
            FROM table as b
            WHERE a.series_id = b.series_id
            AND a.revision_id = b.revision_id)
```