# ZF 1 Mysql WHERE IN query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, greatest-n-per-group

I have a simple query which I can't for the life of me figure out.

I have a table (simplified) "messages" with columns "thread_id" and "messages"

I also have a list of threads I need 10 results from each.

`$list = "1,2,3,4";`

I would do `$db->select()->from("messages")->where("thread_id IN ('?')",$list)->limit(10);`

but that limits only 10 out of total, how would I do 10 out of each thread_id in ZF 1.11 query method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the desired result using this query

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT i1.*
    FROM threadmessage i1
    LEFT JOIN threadmessage i2
      ON (i1.threadid = i2.threadid 
          AND i1.messageid < i2.messageid 
         )
    GROUP BY i1.messageid
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 5
    ORDER BY i1.messageid) A
WHERE A.threadid IN (3,4);
```

I have created a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0ff0/1)

Also you can execute it in aend using the `query` method.

```
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

This is the classic 'N per group' type query. You can get more details from these posts

[How do I select multiple items from each group in a mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304599/how-do-i-select-multiple-items-from-each-group-in-a-mysql-query)
[How to SELECT the newest four items per category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category)
[Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

is not a good solution, but can solve your issue, create sub-sql and union.

```
try{
    $db =  Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $sql=array();
    $idAry=explode(',',$list);
    for($i=0;$i<count($idAry){
        array_push($sql," SELECT * FROM ".$this->_name." where thread_id = ".$idAry[$i]." limit 10 ");
    }   
    $stmt = $db->query(implode(' union ',$sql););
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $result;
}
catch(Exception $ex){
    print_r($ex);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, I'm trying to stay away from Union since there could be more than 8 records in the $list.

Comment: if data is not realtime information,your can flag(top 10 or sequence) your table by batchjob,
Simplify sql syntax. but thread_id seem not , i have no idea don't use union. sorry can't help you.

Comment: Appreciate the effort. It's realtime data :\ Thank you